# Advanced replacing of string in js: could I do it diffrent way?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Code to replace nick-part of address email with stars:

```
"example@gmail.com".replace(/(\S+?)(@\S+?)/, (match, firstGroup, secoundGroup) => {
   return firstGroup.replace(/\S/g, '*') + secoundGroup;
})
```

Result: `*******@gmail.com` (number of stars is the same as in `example`)

Could I do it without callback-function? Or maybe there is better way to do it?

(I simplified regular expression for email)

Comment: I think since an email must only have one @ symbol in it, you could split by @ and then count length of lhs of that split and convert it to stars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```js
console.log("example@gmail.com".replace(/[^@\s](?=[^@\s]*@)/g, '*'));
console.log("example@gmail.com".replace(/[^@\s]/gy, '*'));
```

The [`/[^@\s](?=[^@\s]*@)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/19Ra1C/1) matches any char other than whitespace and `@` that is followed with any number of such chars followed with `@` and replaces with `*`, and [`/[^@\s]/gy`](https://regex101.com/r/19Ra1C/2) matches any char other than `@` and whitespace from the start of the string and the subsequent matches only occur after the end of the previous successful match.

Comment: "Wow" again. Maybe do you (or anybody) know place with exercises with advanced regexp. I don't mean sth like: `write expression for email`, but sth more like from my post?

Comment: @kspacja No idea, but it looks like there are such places, just search for sites that teach to code.

Comment: Sites like what you describe, teach only basics, that why I asked ;) Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to have a fixed number of stars (which is often best, to avoid giving away the length of the actual value), you can do this:

```
"example@gmail.com".replace(/^[^@]+/, "****")
```

Example:

```js
console.log(
    "example@gmail.com".replace(/^[^@]+/, "****")
);
```

Otherwise, if you're using `replace`, you'll need a callback, but it can be simpler, using no capture groups and using `String#repeat`:

```
"example@gmail.com".replace(/^[^@]+/, m => "*".repeat(m.length))
```

Example:

```js
console.log(
    "example@gmail.com".replace(/^[^@]+/, m => "*".repeat(m.length))
);
```

Otherwise, <s>I think you get into using `split` or similar</s> — nope, [Wiktor to the rescue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189747/157247).